# Не сохраняется изображение в память устройства

Tags: android

Не сохраняется файл во внутреннюю память, перепробовал много способов, не сохраняет и не отображает в галерее

```
private boolean saveBitMap(View drawView) {
    File pictureFileDir;

 /*   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        pictureFileDir = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/" + "Отчеты CheckFusion");
        forToast = "SD/Отчеты CheckFusion/";
    } else {*/
        //pictureFileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/" + "Отчеты CheckFusion");
    //pictureFileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ "/" + "Отчеты CheckFusion");
    /*pictureFileDir = new File(Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory()+ "/" + "Отчеты CheckFusion");
        //forToast = "Внутренний накопитель/Отчеты CheckFusion/";
   *//* }*//*
    if (!pictureFileDir.exists()) {
        pictureFileDir.mkdirs();
    }*/
    Date dateNow = new Date();
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat formatForDateNow = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd.MM.yyyy");

    /*String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + "/Отчет CheckFusion " + formatForDateNow.format(dateNow) + ".jpg";
    pictureFile = new File(filename);*/
    //pictureFile= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Отчет CheckFusion " + formatForDateNow.format(dateNow) + ".jpg");
    pictureFile= new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "Отчет CheckFusion " + formatForDateNow.format(dateNow) + ".jpg");
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(drawView);
    try {
        pictureFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, oStream);
        oStream.flush();
        oStream.close();
        galleryAddPic(pictureFile);
        /*     openImage(pictureFile);*/
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
  private void galleryAddPic(File picture) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(picture.getAbsolutePath());
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: В манифесте разрешение на доступ прописано? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: Да в манифесте есть, но это не решает проблемы

Comment: Что вы хотите сохранить? Рисунок?

Comment: да, рисунок хочу сохранить

Comment: bitmap на ноль проверьте, тест записи с простым именем типа test.jpg попробуйте

Comment: Дело точно не в создании bitmap, а именно в сохранении уже изображения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выяснил, что на 11 андроидах и выше недопустим в названиях :, поэтому происходила ошибка.

```
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat formatForDateNow = new SimpleDateFormat("HH**:**mm dd.MM.yyyy");
```